# Update image in image widget (automatically upload?) on another ajax reference field's autocompleteclose event

Tags: media

So I have a few fields that are automagically populated when an entity reference field is 'autocompleted'. Text and Image data (path, etc)

```
...field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
    $element['target_id']['#ajax'] = [
      'event' => 'autocompleteclose',
      'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
    ];
```

This is not an issue with text, but how do I update my image-widget (upload field) with a new image path and automagically upload?

```
...function ajax_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

// For text field this is pretty straightforward.
$response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('input[name="field_....[' . $delta . '][subform][field_..._name][0][value]"', 'val', [$text]));
```

Is it possible to pass a path and filename to an image upload input(image-widget) and maybe mock .click() (or something) to trigger an automatic upload when selecting said field reference autocomplete?

Use case (total of 3 fields):
User completes autocomplete field and two additional fields, say description and image (upload input) are automatically populated/image uploaded. (But I can go back if the user wants and update the image (separately) using normal options on the image upload input, if needed.)

Answer (score 0):

No that isn't possible. You can't automate completion of a file input field, it would be a massive security hole (I think browser plugins for chrome/Firefox can do it, but they run in a different security context to website scripts anyway)

If it were possible, anyone with a website could steal any file from any visitor's computer they fancied.